# SQL Select inside Select doesn't accept WHERE x LIKE %y%

Tags: php, mysql

I want this code to accept more than one WHERE parameter at the bottom, but when the added text comes into play, it returns nothing. It returns what it should without the filter.

What I'm trying to do is filter the results I get from the inner query from user inputted data that gets posted into the PHP code.

Any advice would be helpful at this point.

```
    $OgrenciNo= " AND OgrenciNo LIKE %1005%";
    $sth = $conn->prepare('SELECT t.* FROM (SELECT ogrenciler.OgrenciNo, ogrenciler.adsoyad as adsoyad1,
        dersler.Ders, dersler.DersKodu, tarih.Tarih, ogretmenler.isim, 
        login.adsoyad, onayturu.Onay, mazeretturu.tur,  
        mazeretaciklama.Aciklama, mazeretaciklama.LogTarihi
        FROM ogrenciler, tarih, aratablo, ogretmenler,
        mazeretaciklama, login, dersler, mazeretturu, onayturu
        WHERE aratablo.AciklamaID = mazeretaciklama.AciklamaID
        AND aratablo.TarihID = tarih.TarihID
        AND aratablo.DersID = dersler.DersID
        AND aratablo.OnaylayanID = login.OnaylayanID
        AND aratablo.OnayID = onayturu.OnayID
        AND aratablo.Mazturu = mazeretturu.Mazturu
        AND dersler.OgrGorID = ogretmenler.OgrGorID
        AND mazeretaciklama.OgrenciNo = ogrenciler.OgrenciNo) t
        WHERE LogTarihi > "1900-01-01"
    '.$OgrenciNo
    );
    $sth->execute();
```

Normal results are as follows:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=11)
      'OgrenciNo' => string '1005.02021' (length=10)
      'adsoyad1' => string 'Örnek Öğrenci' (length=13)
      'Ders' => string 'Ders Adı' (length=8)
      'DersKodu' => string 'KOD000' (length=6)
      'Tarih' => string '2016-02-01' (length=10)
      'isim' => string 'Öğretim Elemanı İsmi' (length=20)
      'adsoyad' => string 'ROOT' (length=4)
      'Onay' => string 'Onaylandı' (length=9)
      'tur' => string 'Sınav' (length=5)
      'Aciklama' => string 'hastalık hastası' (length=16)
      'LogTarihi' => string '2016-02-09 09:14:52' (length=19)
  1 => 
    array (size=11)
      'OgrenciNo' => string '1035.02021' (length=10)
      'adsoyad1' => string 'ahmet mehmet' (length=12)
      'Ders' => string 'E-Ticaret Sistem Tasarımı' (length=25)
      'DersKodu' => string 'BIL446' (length=6)
      'Tarih' => string '2016-02-07' (length=10)
      'isim' => string 'Yrd. Doç. Dr. Mustafa Cem Kasapbaşı' (length=35)
      'adsoyad' => string 'Araş. Gör. Erdem Yavuz' (length=22)
      'Onay' => string 'Onaylanmadı' (length=11)
      'tur' => string 'Ders' (length=4)
      'Aciklama' => string 'cenaze vardı' (length=12)
      'LogTarihi' => string '2016-02-11 13:33:53' (length=19)
```

I'm trying to filter out the second result but the LIKE argument doesn't seem to work.

By popular demand here's the whole query after I print it out in the page (P.S. the only thing different from the top one is that it contains "AND OgrenciNo LIKE %1005%" at the end):

```
 SELECT t.* FROM (SELECT ogrenciler.OgrenciNo, ogrenciler.adsoyad as adsoyad1, dersler.Ders, dersler.DersKodu, tarih.Tarih, ogretmenler.isim, login.adsoyad, onayturu.Onay, mazeretturu.tur, mazeretaciklama.Aciklama, mazeretaciklama.LogTarihi FROM ogrenciler, tarih, aratablo, ogretmenler, mazeretaciklama, login, dersler, mazeretturu, onayturu WHERE aratablo.AciklamaID = mazeretaciklama.AciklamaID AND aratablo.TarihID = tarih.TarihID AND aratablo.DersID = dersler.DersID AND aratablo.OnaylayanID = login.OnaylayanID AND aratablo.OnayID = onayturu.OnayID AND aratablo.Mazturu = mazeretturu.Mazturu AND dersler.OgrGorID = ogretmenler.OgrGorID AND mazeretaciklama.OgrenciNo = ogrenciler.OgrenciNo) t WHERE LogTarihi > "1900-01-01" AND OgrenciNo LIKE %1005%
```

Comment: What do mean by `NULL`? It's actually `NULL` or just `""`

Comment: They're not set and when I combine them with the dot (as a string) they add nothing to the string.

Comment: If they are not set then it'll give you `undefined index` error.

Comment: Okay, I've removed those for the time being, I'll add them in a loop or something if I can get this part working first. It still doesn't work though.

Comment: You should send the whole query concatenated with php variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your like condition should be like this. Just add `'` in it. :

```
 $OgrenciNo= " AND OgrenciNo LIKE '%1005%'";
```

Comment: Yep. Absolutely, I'm an idiot for missing that part. Thanks :) (also yeah it works now)